# How to convert to unicode from a char array with an intermediate null charaters

Tags: iphone, unicode, nsstring

i used `+ (id)stringWithCString:mycharaters encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding`

mycharaters is a char array with an intermediate null charaters and end with two null charaters.

```
char mycharaters[20];
```

it contains a unicode string and i want to show it.

but "The array must end with a NULL character; intermediate NULL characters are not allowed."

I wonder how could I show it.

PS:this string contains Chinese and numbers or letters.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string at the single NULL characters, then convert them and put them together again.

I'd say using single and double NULL is quite unusual...

Comment: The datatype is not too uncommon: it's a string of strings. Technically it's terminated by an empty string. COnsider the pair of `'\0'` s at the end. The first `\0` terminates the last non-empty string, and the second terminates the empty string.